# docker-compose stack ( React + Flask )

Tags: reactjs, docker, flask, docker-compose

it's my first time using Docker let alone docker-compose.
Could I get some insight on my docker-compose file to help me get both docker containers up and running.

**Folder Structure**

[image: Folder Structure]

Both of my Dockerfiles work for running each application ( React or Flask ) separately. For example:

**React Container**

```
docker build -t wedding-client .
docker run -dp 3030:3030 wedding-client
```

**Flask Container**

```
docker build -t wedding-server .
docker run -dp 5030:5030 wedding-server
```

So I'm thinking my docker-compose file is the issue. Here are the docker files:

**client/DockerFile**

```
FROM node:alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm -rf ./*
COPY --from=build /app/build .
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 3030
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**server/DockerFile**

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV FLASK_APP server.py
EXPOSE 5030
CMD ["python", "server.py"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    container_name: wedding-server
    build:
      context: server/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - 5030:5030
  client:
    container_name: wedding-client
    build:
      context: client/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - 3030:3030
    depends_on:
      - server
```

**Docker Output:**

[image: Docker Output]

Comment: Why do you disable Docker networking in this setup?  Are you successfully connecting to that container to get that PNG file back; or is there a (textual) error you're getting?  (It looks like a screen shot from running `flask run`, but your Dockerfile specifies a different `CMD`.)

Comment: I use the network_mode: host because I need my docker containers to connect to services on my network outside of docker.

Are you suggesting I remove CMD ["python", "server.py"] in my Flask Dockerfile and add command: flask run in my docker-compose.yml file ?

I am able to see this output since I'm running docker compose up without the -d flag

Comment: You shouldn't need host networking for this.  Putting the `CMD` in the Dockerfile is better practice than putting it in `docker-compose.yml`.  What's the actual output of `docker-compose up` (as text, not an image)?  Does it match the `CMD` you have in the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

**Client Docker File**

```
# Stage 0, "build-stage", based on Node.js to build the frontend
FROM node:alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /app/
RUN npm run build

# Stage 1, based on NGINX to provide a configuration to be used with react-router
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
# RUN apk update && apk add bash
EXPOSE 3005
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**Flask Docker File**

```
FROM python:3.9
RUN mkdir /server
WORKDIR /server
COPY requirements.txt /server/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    build: server
    command: "flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5005"
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=production
      - FLASK_APP=server.py
    ports:
      - "5005:5005"

  client:
    build: client
    ports:
      - '3005:3005'
    links:
      - api
    depends_on:
      - api
```